# What is wrong with this linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

The assignment was to write a function to swap 2 nodes in the list. If the function could swap the nodes regardless of the order, a 10% was awarded. I think my implementation is able to swap 2 elements regardless of the order in the list but I still did not received the bonus marks. Is there anything that I am missing?

I was given a generic node class,

```
public class Node<T> {
    public T val;
    public Node<T> next;

    public Node(T val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

I was also given an interface defined as below,

```
public interface SwapList<T> {

    public void add(T val);

    /**
     * Swaps two elements in the list, but only if @param val1 comes BEFORE @param
     * val2. Solve the problem regardless of the order, for 10% extra. list: A B
     * C -> swap(A,B) will result in the list B A C list: A B C -> swap(B,A)
     * will not swap. list: A C C -> swap(A, D) will throw a
     * NoSuchElementException list: A B C B -> swap (A, B) will result in the
     * list B A C B list: A B C A B B -> swap (A,B) will result in the list B A
     * C A B B a list with one or zero elements cannot do a swap
     */
    public void swap(T val1, T val2);

    public T get(int i);
}
```

and I have my own implementation of this interface as below,

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class SwapListImpl<T> implements SwapList<T> {

    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;
    private int counter;

    public SwapListImpl() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        counter = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T val) {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(val);
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
            tail = node;
        } else {
            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void swap(T val1, T val2) {

        if (counter < 2 || val1.equals(val2))
            return;

        Node<T> current = head;
        Node<T> currentPrev = null;

        Node<T> first = head;
        Node<T> firstPrev = null;
        Node<T> firstNext = first.next;

        Node<T> second = head;
        Node<T> secondPrev = null;
        Node<T> secondNext = second.next;

        boolean foundFirst = false;
        boolean foundSecond = false;
        boolean inOrder = false;

        while (current != null) {
            if (!foundFirst && current.val.equals(val1)) {

                firstPrev = currentPrev;
                first = current;
                firstNext = current.next;

                if (!foundSecond)
                    inOrder = true;

                foundFirst = true;

            }

            if (!foundSecond && current.val.equals(val2)) {

                secondPrev = currentPrev;
                second = current;
                secondNext = current.next;

                if (foundFirst)
                    inOrder = true;

                foundSecond = true;
            }

            if (foundFirst && foundSecond) {

                if (!inOrder) {
                    Node<T> temp = first;
                    first = second;
                    second = temp;

                    temp = firstPrev;
                    firstPrev = secondPrev;
                    secondPrev = temp;

                    temp = firstNext;
                    firstNext = secondNext;
                    secondNext = temp;
                }

                if (firstPrev == null) {

                    head = second;

                    if (first == secondPrev) {
                        second.next = first;
                        first.next = secondNext;
                    } else {
                        second.next = firstNext;
                        secondPrev.next = first;
                        first.next = secondNext;
                    }
                } else {

                    firstPrev.next = second;
                    first.next = secondNext;

                    if (first == secondPrev) {
                        second.next = first;
                    } else {
                        second.next = firstNext;
                        secondPrev.next = first;
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            currentPrev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if (!foundFirst || !foundSecond) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int i) {
        if (i < counter) {
            Node<T> node = head;
            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++) {
                node = node.next;
            }
            return node.val;
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  How do you know this code doesn't work?

Comment: Are you allowed to add on to the generic node class?

Comment: @LouisWasserman This is marked by school auto mark system

Comment: What does that system say?  You say that it has to swap two elements in any order, and it doesn't, but it does.

Comment: @A.R.S. Yes, it is allowed to modify the node class.

Comment: @The problem is here, because I have already get the basic mark. But I want to get that 10%. The system gave me 40 marks, without saying any problem. But there is 10 marks extra.

Comment: what enhancement does it need to get the extra 10 marks, the wording is kind of ambiguous?

Comment: Does the system handle the bonus marks or does the professor?

Comment: @KDiTraglia "Solve the problem regardless of the order, for 10% extra." - from the interface definition

Comment: @null where's the mark, in the object you're sending to the list or somewhere else? Because the main problem is that community people can't see it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I think the problem is only at that 10% part, because if my Node class or Swap function are wrong, I wont event get the basic marks.

Comment: Did you try inputting all the test data it uses and see what comes out?

Comment: @KDiTraglia Yes, since yesterday.

Comment: @null what I'm trying to say is that your post doesn't have any code where we can see how the 10% extra can apply. Maybe is for extra points in solving the problem, or in another class that you haven't posted. If is the last, please post all the classes involved in this problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks, but all are here.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza there is a node class, an interface, that all they give. the requirement is on the interface definition already. What I have to do is implements the interface, and write the function implementation.

Comment: @null well have luck finding how to apply 10% to nothing that we can't see.

Comment: Can you show us a test case where the 10% would be awarded?

Comment: @acattle Original requirement: "Swaps two elements in the list, but only if param val1 comes BEFORE param VAL2"; Solve this following will get 10% extra {A B C} -> Swap(B, A) -> {B A C}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the swap itself: you forgot to set the tail.

Here is a small test for exactly that problem:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  SwapListImpl<String> list = new SwapListImpl<String>();
  list.add("A");
  list.add("B");
  list.add("C");

  list.swap("A", "C");

  assertEquals("C", list.get(0));
  assertEquals("C", list.getHead().val);
  assertEquals("B", list.get(1));
  assertEquals("A", list.get(2));
  assertEquals("A", list.getTail().val);

  list.add("D");

  assertEquals("C", list.get(0));
  assertEquals("C", list.getHead().val);
  assertEquals("B", list.get(1));
  assertEquals("A", list.get(2));
  assertEquals("D", list.get(3));
  assertEquals("D", list.getTail().val);

  list.swap("A", "C");

  assertEquals("A", list.get(0));
  assertEquals("A", list.getHead().val);
  assertEquals("B", list.get(1));
  assertEquals("C", list.get(2));
  assertEquals("D", list.get(3));
  assertEquals("D", list.getTail().val);

  list.swap("C", "B");

  assertEquals("A", list.get(0));
  assertEquals("A", list.getHead().val);
  assertEquals("C", list.get(1));
  assertEquals("B", list.get(2));
  assertEquals("D", list.get(3));
  assertEquals("D", list.getTail().val);
}
```

You see I added two methods to the list, for getting the head and tail, but that's not important - the test would even fail without the explicit test for head and tail. The extra methods for the list are really simple:

```
  public Node<T> getTail() {
      return this.tail;
    }

    public Node<T> getHead() {
      return this.head;
    }
```

The problem of not setting tail occurs when swapping the last element of the list and then adding another element.

Here is a fixed version of the actual swap:

```
  if (foundFirst && foundSecond) {

    if (second == this.tail) {
      this.tail = first;
    } else if (first == this.tail) {
      this.tail = second;
    }

    if (first == this.head) {
      this.head = second;
    } else if (second == this.head) {
      this.head = first;
    }

    if (firstPrev == second) {
      first.next = second;
    } else {
      if (firstPrev != null) {
        firstPrev.next = second;
      }
      first.next = secondNext;
    }
    if (secondPrev == first) {
      second.next = first;
    } else {
      if (secondPrev != first && secondPrev != null) {
        secondPrev.next = first;
      }
      second.next = firstNext;
    }
    break;
  }
```

You see I didn't add lines to your code - instead I wrote the code in another way. I think it's more readable, but you also can try just to set the tail in the correct way. But it was too complex for me, so I reduced the complexity of that code - that's the reason why I rewrote it.

I would suggest, that you use first and second for the first/second occurence and not for the first/second argument. I think that would improve the readability of the method. But that's another point ;-)

Hope that helps - so the order IMHO is not the problem, but the tail.

Comment: Bertram thanks for pointing out the problem. i have fixed the problem, but still unable to get that extra, but this is perfect. thanks a lot! I have learnt lessons. Your solution is far more elegant than mine.

Comment: @null pity that you didn't get the bonus. Maybe you should ask your professor for the exact reason.
The complete list still can be far more elegant, here are some hints: 1. You don't need `firstNext` and `secondNext` in the swap, 2. You don't need `inOrder` anymore, 3. consider changing the content of `first*` and `second*` as I mentioned at the end of my answer and last 4. consider throwing an IOOB-Exc. also when `get(int)` is invoked with values less than zero.

Comment: thanks, I just found a bug in your program, imgae {ABCD} then swap(C,B),you will "firstPrev.next = second" which is second point to itself.

Comment: @null Oh I see, yes - I corrected the code above and extended the test case.

Comment: I'm wondering why I can't come out the most elegant solution when I was facing this problem. I feel I'm so stupid...

Comment: Nobody is perfect - you have to learn things like that. And I'm not programming the most elegant solutions either. But with each mistake I make I learn for the future ..

Comment: I think your answer is very well written and I was going to give it a +1 until you gave him the code. Typically when there's a `homework` tag you don't want to do that (it's to prevent people from coming here and asking us to do their homework for them). In this case I don't think it deserves a -1, but in the future you should be aware of that.

Comment: @BertramNudelbach Are firstNext and secondNext still necessary?

Comment: @null at least `firstNext` is still needed, as we override the value of `first.next` but still want the old value `first.next` pointed to.
@acattle okay, I didn't notice that and will be careful in future!